Visual Studios Assembly Language LNK1104 cannot open file 'C:\Users\jerry\Source\repos\CA4\\Debug\CA4.exe' error
I am having a problem with running the code below due to the error mentioned in the title. It is the exact same code that my professor used, but for some reason it keeps giving this error. After unpluging and replugging in specific part of the code, the error always seems to occur when "jz None" get executed. However, jz worked perfectly fine on my other assignemnts, so I don't know why it is causing this error. I also followed the path that it took to try and find the .exe file and saw that no .exe file was formed in that Debug folder. If anyone can figure out what is going on, please tell me because I have no idea if this is a problem with the code or my Visual Studio.
For more context, the assignemnt is trying to make us use test to see if the binary in bl contain 1 at bit 4, 5, or 6. Jz is used here to make it jump to what happen if the test result in all zeros. We also have to print out if it contain this set using Irvine library.
.386
.model flat,stdcall
.stack 4096
ExitProcess PROTO dwExitCode:DWORD


INCLUDE C:\Users\jerry\Source\Irvine\irvine32.inc
includelib C:\Users\jerry\Source\Irvine\irvine32.lib

.data
prompt1 BYTE "Set",0
prompt2 BYTE "Not set",0

.code
main PROC

    mov bl, 01101010b
    test bl, 01110000b

    jz None

    mov edx, OFFSET prompt1
    call WriteString
    call Crlf

    jmp Next


None:
    mov edx, OFFSET prompt2
    call WriteString
    call Crlf

Next:

    INVOKE ExitProcess,0

main ENDP
END main

I was just using the same code that my professor used and expected to get what he got, which would be "Set" being printed. However, what I got was this error that only occurs when jz get executed. This then led me to finding out that no .exe file was actually formed in the Debug folder, and that this error only happen on this code specifially because it did not happen in my other codes where I used jz.

Do you get any build errors?

We figured out that it was because I had an updated version of Visual Studio, so some stuff from the old Irvine library wouldn't work for me. Luckily, my college gave us web terminals, so I just did my assembly coding there.
